# execute python script when directory is not empty - Directory Monitoring

Tags: python, linux, shell, daemon

I have a python script that converts images and videos withing a directory. 
The problem, the python script executes manually but I need the script to execute automatically when a file is dropped into the directory under a *linux platform*.

What would be the best way to set a python script to watch/monitor a directory?

I've looked into many options but not sure which one just simply sets the script to execute when files are dropped into a directory.

Thank in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'clean' way to do this is using the [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) system. There is the [Pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) project if you want to use Python to interface with it.

You don't have to use inotify directly though - there are tools like [icrond](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/) you can hook into. In fact, the person at that link looks to be trying to do something very similar to what you want - check it out.

Brute force, you could use [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch), though that just runs a command periodically, not only when something changes.

Comment: @knittledan: You're welcome! Does it answer your question? If so, you should accept it (green check mark).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PyInotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify)

Or for an easier example:

[PyInotify Tutorial](http://trac.dbzteam.org/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Use pyinotify:

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

A tutorial is here: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial